# How to change schema of multiple PostgreSQL tables in one operation?

Tags: postgresql, schema, migrate, postgresql-9.1

I have a PostgreSQL 9.1 database with 100 or so tables that were loaded into the 'public' schema.  I would like to move those tables (but not all of the functions in 'public') to a 'data' schema.

I know that I can use the following to move 1 table at a time.

```
ALTER TABLE [tablename] SET SCHEMA [new_schema]
```

Is it possible to move all of the tables to the new schema in one operation?  If so, what would be the most efficient way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

[DO](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-do.html) will do the trick:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
    row record;
BEGIN
    FOR row IN SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = 'public' -- and other conditions, if needed
    LOOP
        EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE public.%I SET SCHEMA [new_schema];', row.tablename);
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: That sounds exactly like what I was imagining.  Since I'm new to postgres, where should I run this?  I tried in pgAdmin 3 (windows) and psql command line, but got errors in both cases.  Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: It's just a piece of SQL, run it just like any query in your favorite SQL-client. You could use psql, pgAdmin3 or something like that.

Comment: The error i get from pgAdmin3 is: "ERROR: type "quote_ident" does not exist.  SQL state: 42704.  Context: PL/pgSQL function "inline_code_block" line 5 at EXECUTE statement."

Comment: Sorry, typo fixed. Please try again.

Comment: The typo was the issue.  Thanks so much for your help.  It worked like a charm!

Comment: Excellent question and answer.

Comment: You can move your functions as well with:
`DO$$
DECLARE
    row record;
    sql text = E'\n';
BEGIN
    FOR row IN
  select proname::text as proname,
      pg_get_function_identity_arguments(p.oid) AS params
  from pg_proc p
  JOIN pg_type t on p.prorettype = t.oid
  JOIN pg_namespace n on n.oid = p.pronamespace
  LEFT JOIN pg_description d on p.oid = d.objoid
  WHERE nspname = 'public'
    LOOP
  sql = CONCAT(sql, E'\n',
   'ALTER FUNCTION public.', row.proname,
   '(', row.params, ') SET schema [new_schema];');
    END LOOP;
    EXECUTE sql;
END;$$;`

Comment: And you'll probably want the sequences, too:
DO
$$
DECLARE
    row record;
BEGIN
    FOR row IN SELECT sequence_name FROM information_schema.sequences WHERE sequence_schema = 'public'
    LOOP
        EXECUTE 'ALTER SEQUENCE public.' || quote_ident(row.sequence_name) || ' SET SCHEMA [new_schema];';
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;

Comment: I read that `quote_ident` should be replaced with `format()`. Does this apply here, too?
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31529945/

Comment: @PaulfromC: Yes, I would use format() now

Answer (score 0):

```
-- ####### USING DBEAVER WHICH SUPPORT VARIABLES ########

-- @@@ ANSWER_1 -- USING DO @@@--------

-- Step1: Set variables one by one

@set _SCHEMA = 'public'
@set _COLUMN = 'dml_status'
@set _DATA_TYPE = 'integer'
@set _DEFAULT = '1'

-- Step2: Call the below procedure

DO
$$
DECLARE
row record;
query varchar;
BEGIN
FOR ROW IN SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables  WHERE table_schema = ${_SCHEMA}
LOOP
 query :='ALTER TABLE public.' || quote_ident(row.table_name) ||' ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS '||${_COLUMN} || ' ' || ${_DATA_TYPE} ||' not null default ' || ${_DEFAULT} || ';' ;
execute query;
END LOOP;
END;
$$;


-- @@@ ANSWER_2 -- STORE PROCEDURE FN @@@--------


DROP FUNCTION addColumnToMultipleTables cascade;
create or replace function addColumnToMultipleTables()
returns void
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
as $$
DECLARE
row record;
query varchar;
BEGIN
FOR ROW IN SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables  WHERE table_schema = ${_SCHEMA}
LOOP
 query :='ALTER TABLE public.' || quote_ident(row.table_name) ||' ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS '||${_COLUMN} || ' ' || ${_DATA_TYPE} ||' not null default ' || ${_DEFAULT} || ';' ;
 raise info 'query : % ', query;
execute query;
END LOOP;
END;
$$;

select addColumnToMultipleTables();
```