# Have attribute set to specific value on every query

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

##### The setup:

I use [psycopg2](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/index.html#) to access a (PostgreSQL) database I constructed in SQL.
I wanted to have different users, which can only access their own rows in a table. Therefore I added a `UserId` attribute to every table in the scheme. The value of UserId is available as a variable (let us name it `pyUserId`) to the program on execution.
All my calls to `curs.execute()` go through one function defined by me.

##### What I want to achieve:

Is it possible that I centrally set the value for an attribute, like `UserId=pyUserId`, for each query?
Else I had to pass the pyUserId as data on every query I already constructed, which also violates DRY, I suspect.

For example:
`SELECT UserName FROM Users WHERE Age < 30` becomes:
`SELECT UserName FROM Users WHERE Age < 30 AND UserId = pyUserId`
or
`INSERT INTO Profiles (Name, Bio, SoAccount) VALUES ('jon', 'blah...', '22656')` becomes
`INSERT INTO Profiles (Name, Bio, SoAccount, UserId) VALUES ('jon', 'blah...', '22656', pyUserId)`

Same for `DELETE` etc.

#### What I tried:

- For `INSERT` [it is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745156/how-do-i-change-column-default-value-in-postgresql) to dynamically ALTER the PostgreSQL DEFAULT constraint. But this would only apply to inserts.
- According to [string composition](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) in psycopg2 docs, I can manipulate the SQL query string. But I guess there are a lot of pitfalls, operating on SQL strings.
- However, maybe there is a way to do this by manipulation of the prepared statement or the parse tree.
- I am not sure, if the idea is possible at all. If it is not, please explain why.

Comment: For information, PostgreSQL implements [row level security](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ddl-rowsecurity.html), which does what  want (I think), but you would need to connect as the user for it to be effective (although the article linked to in [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/174667/151124) shows a way it could be done).

Comment: Row level security seems like what I want. All answers though recommend or expect different roles for different users. To me it seems like there are two apporaches: 1. Implement roles for different users. Then use RLS as in the offical docs. 2. Follow the answer with signed session variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snakecharmer's comment helped me implement the following.

Have an attribute `UserId` in all tables where specific rows belong to specific users:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    UserId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    user_attributes ...

CREATE TABLE some_table (
    UserId INTEGER REFERENCES Users(UserId) 
    DEFAULT current_setting('my_app.CurrentUserId')::INTEGER NOT NULL,
    some_attribute INTEGER, ...
```

Based on [this tutorial](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/application-users-vs-row-level-security/): Define a session variable which is set, when a user is authenticated and is above used as `DEFAULT`:

```py
SQL = "SET my_app.CurrentUserId = %s"
data = (self.__userId, )
cur.execute(SQL, data)
```

Implement [Row-Level Security](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html), to create a policy which only allows access where `UserId` is equal to the session variable:

```
DO -- Create a loop over all tables to create a policy and enable it for them
$$
DECLARE
    row record;
BEGIN
    FOR row IN SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables AS t
        WHERE t.schemaname = 'public' 
        AND NOT t.tablename ~* 'exclude|tables|regex'
    LOOP
        EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE %I ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;', row.tablename); 
        EXECUTE format('CREATE POLICY isolateUserId ON %I TO some_user 
                            USING (UserId = current_setting(''my_app.CurrentUserId'')::INTEGER);', row.tablename); -- Escape ' !
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

#### How it works:

- This works well, because only a few tables do not get RLS, so they can easily be removed in the regex.
- `some_user` is the one you use in psycopg2 to connect to the database.
- I copied [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218768/how-to-change-schema-of-multiple-postgresql-tables-in-one-operation) for the loop.
- The way this works is explained well in the linked article. TL;DR: It is made sure that a user always creates items with their own UserId, by the combination of the session variable and default value. Session variable and policy make sure that a user only sees/alters/deletes rows where their own UserId is present.